# Avoid image reload on state update

Tags: angular, state-management, ngxs

I'm using NGXS as my state manager.
I have a "menuItems" object that populates my "sidenav" component:

```
export const menuItems: Array<MenuItem> = [


{
    icon: 'assets/circle-logo.png',
    label: 'Home',
    route: '/home',
    selected: false
  },
  {
    icon: 'assets/circle-logo.png',
    label: 'Customers',
    route: '/customers',
    selected: false
  },
  {
    icon: 'assets/circle-logo.png',
    label: 'Entries',
    route: '/entries',
    selected: false
  }];
```

when the application load the first time the image on the "icon" property is loaded normally.

[image]

The state is updated when I click on a item from my sidenav:

[image]

Then an index is send to the state, to change the property selected to "true" and highlight the item, as seen in the image above.

My problem is when I update the "menuItems" state the "logo-image" is reloaded again. I little "blink" is visible on the screen when the image load again.

[image]

This is the code of my sidenav state:

```
import { State, Action, StateContext } from '@ngxs/store';
import { MenuItem } from '@shared/types';
import { menuItems } from '@components/sidenav/menu-items';

export class SelectMenuItem {
  static readonly type = 'SelectMenuItem';
  constructor(public itemIndex: number) {}
}

@State<Array<MenuItem>>({
  name: 'menuItems',
  defaults: menuItems
})
export class SideNavState {
  @Action(SelectMenuItem)
  selectMenuItem(ctx: StateContext<Array<MenuItem>>, action: SelectMenuItem) {
    const { getState, setState } = ctx;
    const { itemIndex } = action;
    const state = getState();
    const currentItem = state.findIndex(s => s.selected);

    if (currentItem !== itemIndex) {
      const newState = state.map((item, index) => {
        if (currentItem > -1 && currentItem === index) {
          item = { ...item, selected: false };
        }
        if (itemIndex === index) {
          item = { ...item, selected: true };
        }
        return item;
      });
      setState(newState);
    }
  }
}
```

Am I not updating correctly the state, or there is a workaround for this behavior?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation you could use a trackby function to prevent angular from redrawing

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avoid-image-reload-on-state-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that your template is reloading the entire list each item you want to select an item - because you are calling `setState`, which will cause anything subscribed to your state to receive an update.

I'd suggest modelling your state differently e.g.

```
export class SelectMenuItem {
  static readonly type = 'SelectMenuItem';
  constructor(public itemIndex: number) {}
}

// In the state model, capture the selected item/index
// separate from the list of menu items.
interface MenuItemStateModel { 
  selectedItem: number,
  menuItems: MenuItem[]
}

@State<MenuItemStateMode>({
  name: 'menuItems',
  defaults: {
    selectedItem: null,
    menuItems: []
  }
})
export class MenuItemState { 

  @Action(SelectMenuItem)
  selectItem({patchState}: StateContext<MenuItemStateModel>, action: SelectMenuItem) { 
    patchState({selectedItem: action.itemIndex});
  }

  // .. Load the menu items from API (or hardcoded?)

}
```

Then remove the 'selected' property from your menuItem type.  In the template if you then want to show it highlighted you can bind a style according to whether the `itemIndex === state.selectedItem`.

This way you don't modify the list when items are selected/unselected.

Comment: Never thought on changing the state structure. thanks for the solution.

Comment: I still recommend a track by function when ngFor ing data from state, state maybe immutable.

Comment: Yep, can still use trackby